# Fedora 23: mail command not working

Tags: email, smtp, fedora-23

On Fedora 21, I had a simple script for sending emails

```
mail -a /tmp/attachment.txt -s "..." someone@somewhere.com
```

On Fedora 23, this no longer works.

```
No configuration file found at /home/mike/.esmtprc or /etc/esmtprc
```

I created the file and assigned correct permissions to it.

```
hostname = localhost.localdomain:25
```

(That's what Fedora 21 would send emails from: mike@localhost.localdomain.)

Well, now I'm getting

```
SMTP server problem Connection refused
```

**Question: how do I get the mail command to work on Fedora 23?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, seems like Fedora 21 must have had an email server running by default, but Fedora 23 does not.

In my

```
~/.esmtprc
```

I had to add

```
hostname = [SMTP SERVER THAT WORKS]:25
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -d %T"
```

And that worked. Thanks everyone anyway!